# show Videobox on document.ready

Tags: jquery, video, mootools

Now according to the author's [site](http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net/) i should be able to load videobox on document ready by just calling it like this:

```
Videobox.open("your video page url","your caption","vidbox width height");
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setStyles' of undefined
   Videobox.positionvideobox.js:75
   Videobox.openvideobox.js:55
   (anonymous function)opcion2.html:13
```

this is being tested in Chrome

here's my code it's just simple cause I'm testing this functionality:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/videobox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />   

     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/videobox.js"></script>
     <script language="javascript">
          Videobox.open('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhtIydTmOVU', 'Test', 'vidbox 979 416');

     </script>

   </head>

   <body>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put that in a document.ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    Videobox.open("your video page url","your caption","vidbox width height");
});
```

Or just move your original script section that made this call to the end of your `body`

---

The author's site just says:

> You can also start your videos with javascript.
>
> ```
> Videobox.open("your video page url","your caption","vidbox widht height");
> ```

He never said you could call this before your dom was ready.